# Overlay image in terminal using ueberzug within C

Tags: c, image, command-line, terminal, process

With the [ueberzug](https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug) library, it is possible to overlay images in terminal windows under X11.
The library is written in python - examples for how to use the library are provided for bash and python.

To overlay an image in the terminal, one can simply run `ueberzug layer` and then enter a json formatted string like `{"action": "add", "x": 0, "y": 0, "identifier": "test", "path": "/tmp/image.jpg"}`. This works flawlessly.

I am trying to call this process in C.
If I understand it correctly, I just have to spawn a new process, and then write to its stdin, which is normally a simple task.

However, in my case I can see the image flicker up for a fraction of a second before the application terminates. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void run_ueberzug()
{
    FILE *output;
    output = popen("ueberzug layer", "w");

    if (!output)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect parameters or too many files.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(output, "{\"action\": \"add\", \"x\": 0, \"y\": 0, \"identifier\": \"test\", \"path\": \"/tmp/image.jpg\"}\n");
    if (ferror(output))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Output to stream failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pclose(output) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not run more or other error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
}

int main(void)
{
    run_ueberzug();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix that the image is shown properly? (Not for just a fraction of a second)

Furthermore, should I run this in a separate thread? The goal is to be able to control the behavior of ueberzug properly, aka programatically show the image or unshow/remove the image, without blocking the main application.

Comment: You probably need to have a child process which doesn't die (until some interrupt like Ctrl + C) when the parent process dies. Currently what I assume is the C program ends and so does the `popen` inside it.

Comment: Or maybe, you don't need a child process at all, but rather a while loop which will run until some interrupt is fired.

Comment: @kiner_shah Even trying to add a sleep after the process was executed had no effect on properly showing the image, hence I am unsure if a while loop that runs until an interrupt is fired will make a difference. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sleep before `pclose` or after `pclose`?

Comment: Before pclose. Can you reproduce the problem in your side?

Comment: I will have to setup the library for reproducing - I was trying to see if it could be solved without that.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts :) The library does not require to much setup - ueberzug can be installed directly via pip.

Comment: Can you try and call a `fflush(output) ` right after fprintf and before sleep/pclose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments, the following solution based on yours works:

- By `popen` you fork a process, create a bidirectional pipe and start the command in the sub-shell
- Subsequently, one writes to the pipe, issueing commands to ueberzug
- the pipe however has to be `fflush`ed, otherwise it's transferred only when the process exits
- the signal handler catches the ueberzug child-process if the sub-shell is killed/quits

Meanwhile, `main` may continue running your code. The code below cycles through 3 images.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define ERROR(text,error) do { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:%s error:%d\n", (text), error); exit(error); } while(0)

static FILE *output = NULL;

void run_ueberzug()
{
    output = popen("/home/hpcraink/.local/bin/ueberzug layer --parser json ", "w");
    if (!output)
        ERROR("Incorrect parameters or too many files", errno);
}

void mysighandler(int signal) {
    int wstatus;
    wait(&wstatus);
    if (pclose(output) != 0)
        ERROR("Could not run more or other error", errno);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    const char * files[] = {
      "img0.jpg",
      "img1.jpg",
      "img2.jpg",
    };
    run_ueberzug(); 
    signal(SIGCHLD, &mysighandler);

    while (1) {
            fprintf(output, "{\"action\": \"remove\", \"identifier\": \"img\"}\n");
            fprintf(output, "{\"action\": \"add\", \"x\": 0, \"y\": 0, \"identifier\": \"img\", \"path\": \"%s\"}\n", files[i]);
            fflush(output);
            i = (i + 1) % (sizeof(files)/sizeof(files[0]));
            sleep(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to achieve, the flushing was what I forgot.